# How to write to textfile in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, export, text-files

How would I output to a text file to the user's hard drive from SQL Server 2008?  In the scenario the user's hard drive is the same hard drive containing the SQL Server.

I don't want the output to be a .csv file or an xml file, just plain text.  I also need to do this in the code. I don't want the user to have to manually click export or another GUI button  everytime.  My plan is to include this functionality in a stored procedure.

Comment: Where are you expecting to place this text file? On the user's hard drive? Otherwise, aren't they going to have to go do something else to retrieve the file?

Comment: Yes on the user's hard drive.

Comment: That is going to be tough. Are all of your users' workstations in the domain, and is the SQL Server service running as a domain admin account (or has otherwise been granted access to each user's system)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to mention which version of SQL Server you're using, but assuming SQL Server 2005 or better, I would use SQLCLR for this, not xp_cmdshell or sp_OACreate. See [the earliest answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626323/sql-server-how-to-write-variables-and-query-results-to-text-file).

Comment: Preferably it would work for SQL Server 2000, 2005, and 2008.

Comment: You know that SQL Server 2000 is no longer in mainstream support from Microsoft, right?

Comment: I'm going to give SQLCLR a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'.

Comment: I tried that but I am getting an error when trying to call OpenTextFile.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a BCP out?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Might have an issue getting it directly to the users hard drive depending on the network setup.  It might be worth a shot.

bcp TABLENAME out FILEPATH OPTIONS